# Visual Studio Code - Save file before build

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to automatically save all changed files before build? It's a bit tedious to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature seems to have been implemented now:
Goto: File > Preferences > Settings
In "Search Settings" box at top, enter "Save".
Multiple matches will be listed.
Scroll down to: **Task: Save Before Run** and select: **Always save all editors before running**
Before leaving, take a moment to review some of the other language-specific options to see if any of them is of interest.

Comment: This does not work reliably. For example, it doesn't work with Python, as far as I can tell.

Comment: As of recent, for some reason this setting is already enabled for me but when i run a python file it opens a file dialog asking me to save it manually, which is incredibly annoying. makes my blood boil.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't need to *build* but rather *run* the file, then you can adjust the [Code Runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) settings by adjusting your user settings. Settings can be accessed in `file > preferences > settings` (or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>comma</kbd>.)

To **save the current file before running** add the line below to your User Settings:

```
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
```

or to **save all files before running**, add this line:

```
"code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
```

I also added this shortcut key(keybinding) to `file > preferences > keyboard shortcuts > keybindings.json`

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "code-runner.run"
},
```

Now I can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and all the magic happens.

Comment: I did a screen record: [link](https://imgur.com/2P3iPdA)

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there is an open feature request for this - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21342

The reverse thing (build on save) can be done, for example, with extension "Trigger Task on Save" (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.triggertaskonsave)

Comment: As of sometime in 2017, running tasks does automatically save all: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21342#issuecomment-343141199

The issue will remain open until the behavior can be controlled: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21342#issuecomment-432593879

Answer (score 1):

Setting `files.autoSave` to `afterDelay` is probably your best alternative. You can combine it with decreasing `autoSaveDelay` so that files are autosaved quickly without you having to do anything.

```
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"files.autoSaveDelay": 100,
```

Comment: Since I'm using an extension to reformat my code after save, using autosave could be a pain because code will literally slip away from my cursor.