# automatic save and erase of a modified script in VSC before running it once again

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, configuration

I'm new to python coding.

My spec's are:

```
MacBook Pro macOs 10.14.6 (Mojave).
Python 3.9.0 loaded october 5, 2020.
Visual Studio Code 1.49.3
```

I would like in a given file.py, to automatically :
Save the modified script and
Erase the previous output in the output window, before running the new modified code.

In VSC, I have tried without success:

"save" "autosave", then
in "settings.json" to add: "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun" : true.

According to a contributor's suggestion (Molly Wang) , I have added in settings.json :

"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,

But in VSC output window, neither the autosave nor the automatic erase works, and I don't understand why.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAF0B.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code - Save file before build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643629/visual-studio-code-save-file-before-build)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in settings.json:

```
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have followed your suggestions : the autosave works perfectly, but there is still no previous output clearing. Any idea ?

Comment: This setting should work in OUTPUT which only show the latest result. Do you mean clear previous result in TERMINAL?

Comment: My script is actually running in the VSC output window. But despite adding in settings.json the two lines of user settings you suggested me yesterday , I notice today there is neither  autosave of modifications I do in my script, nor automatic erasing of the previous code (although these two features work perfectly in Pycharm). This is somewhat disturbing. I apparently can't insert any screenshot in this answer box. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: you can post the screenshot in your question